# Issue Laravel Relationships

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I have two tables `users` and `notes` and I'm trying to relate to them a certain way but when I am created my `hasMany` and `belongTo` the script does not load and times out after a certain amount of time.

I am trying to create a basic note-adding system so that you can add notes onto a user's account. I have successfully established a `hasMany` relationship to users who have notes on their account, however, I'm trying to define a relationship on `notes` where it brings through the user who has created the note.

My database is laid out like so:

**Users:**

```
`id`, `username`, `password`

1   , Connor    , hash
```

**Notes:**

```
`id`, `note`, `user_id`, `user_id_created`

1   , Hello ,  1       , 1
```

So this means that `user ID 1` has created a note against themself, so in my User model I use:

```
class User { 
    public function notes(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Note");
    }
    public function created_notes(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Note", "id", "user_id_created");
    }
}
```

And then in my Notes model I use:

```
class Note {
    protected $with = ['created_by']
    public function created_by(){
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User", "user_id_created", "id");
    }
}
```

However, when I've done this, and try and use `$with = ['created_by']` on my Note's model, the script crashes and doesn't load at all.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Please display your query (i.e $with = ['created_by'])

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean, sorry?

Comment: Could you try converting your method names to camel case (ie, change to `createdBy()` and `createdNotes()`) and change the `$with` parameter to reflect that? Laravel may be converting from snake case to do the eager loading.

Comment: Paste your whole query

Comment: @benj This has the same effect (script refuses to load).

Comment: What is the end result you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

User Model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function notes(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Note");
    }
    public function created_notes(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Note", "id", "user_id_created");
    }
}
```

Note Model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Note extends Model {
    protected $with = ['created_by'];

    public function created_by()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User", "user_id_created", "id");
    }
}
```

Tinker Results:

```
>>> $note = App\Note::find(1)
=> App\Note {#771
     id: 1,
     note: "1",
     user_id: 1,
     user_id_created: 1,
     created_at: "2018-05-21 08:58:32",
     updated_at: "2018-05-21 08:58:32",
     created_by: App\User {#778
       id: 1,
       name: "bob",
       email: "bob@example.com",
       created_at: "2018-05-21 08:58:22",
       updated_at: "2018-05-21 08:58:22",
     },
   }
```

Comment: For some reason, that is not loading the page at all. I did this previously and it didn't load.

Comment: Laravel threw a maximum 60 seconds load error on Whoops!

Comment: No tinker doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Got a "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException  : Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1576960 bytes)" when used through TInker

Comment: I think the issue is when I use $with = ['notes'] on my User table. It must be repeating itself infinitely.

Comment: Yeah, that will create an infinite loop for sure

Comment: Can't think of any way around this without losing the ability to   do `App\User::find(1)->notes()` and `App\User::find(1)->notes()->created_by()`;

Answer (score -1):

> Note Model

```
class Note extends Model
{

    protected $table='notes';
    public $primaryKey='id';
    protected $fillable = ['id','note','user_id','user_id_created'];

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }

}
```

> User Model

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table='users';
    public $primaryKey='id';

    protected $fillable = ['username'];
    protected $hidden = ['password'];


    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
   }
}
```

> in Your Controller

```
use App\Note;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class NotesController extends Controller
{

    public function get_notes(Request $request){
      $notes=Note::with('user')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
      return response()->json($notes);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this incorporate the user who created the note– this will only attach the note to the user who it related and not bring in the user who created it.

Comment: see `get_notes()` method , we have used `with('user')`

Answer (score -1):

The users model should be

```
class User { 
    public function notes(){
        return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
    }
}
```

And Notes model

```
class Note {
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Now simply call the user() from the notes instance to get the details of the user who created the note.

Comment: This is not what I wanted; I need the note to bring in the user who created it by the column user_id_created.

Comment: can you explain what you exactly wanted??

Comment: I wanted to people to use Note::find(1)->createdBy() which brings in the user that corrosponds to the column user_id_created on the Notes table.